# How to do Automate Testing for GPS based android mobile applications?

Tags: android, mobile, automation, automated-tests

How to do  Automate Testing for GPS based android mobile applications? 
I need to send gps location to my android application continuously throughout application running on the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Location Services permission to mock location...

```
"android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
```

and then in your java code,

```
// Set location by setting the latitude, longitude and may be the altitude...
String[] MockLoc = str.split(",");
Location location = new Location(mocLocationProvider);            
Double lat = Double.valueOf(MockLoc[0]);
location.setLatitude(lat);
Double longi = Double.valueOf(MockLoc[1]);
location.setLongitude(longi);
Double alti = Double.valueOf(MockLoc[2]);
location.setAltitude(alti);
```